# what should I do make it print output

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var test = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var mapObj = {
    A: 'Eh'
  };

  test = test.replace(/A/g,
    function(matched) {
      return mapObj[matched];

    })

  var check = document.getElementById("check");
  check.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerText = test;
  }, false);
}, false);
```

```css
BODY {
  width: 520px;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="myText"></textarea>


  <button id="check">translate</button>

  <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id='demo' readonly><p id='demo'></p></textarea>


</body>

</html>
```

it's a part of my code, it's a translator
it is supposed to work as I click the translate button then print the output in the textarea box but it doesn't what should I do make it work? I would appreciate the answer in any types very much

Comment: You're setting `test` when the page is loaded, not when the user enters something in the texarea and clicks the `translate` button.

Comment: You have two `id="demo"`. IDs need to be unique.

Comment: To change the contents of a textarea, you should assign to its `value`, not `innerText`.

Answer (score 1):

Your test variable didn't get updated when you press the button. I've changed the code a bit to give you the idea from where to start. Take a look:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var check = document.getElementById("check");
  check.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var test = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    var mapObj = {
      A: 'Eh'
    };

    test = test.replace(/A/g,
      function(matched) {
        return mapObj[matched];

    })
    
    document.getElementById('demo').innerText = test;
  }, false);
}, false);
```

```css
BODY {
  width: 520px;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="myText">Type "A" and press translate.</textarea>


  <button id="check">translate</button>

  <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id='demo' readonly></textarea>


</body>

</html>
```